# How to get .on("change") to work with gldatepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a date select box that when a date is selected, the date will be used in a calculation.

```
 <? echo $this->Form->input( 'start_date', array( 'label' => __('Show only accounts made since:'), 'value' => '', 'readonly' => 'readonly' ) ); ?>
```

The Javascript I tried:

```
$('#start_date').glDatePicker({ cssName: 'darkneon'});
$("#start_date").on("change",function() {
    var date = this.value;
    console.log (date);
    do_stuff(date);

});
```

The console shows nothing when I select a date. I am clearly missing something. Is on-change even the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#start_date').glDatePicker({ 
    cssName: 'darkneon',
    onClick: function(target, cell, date, data) {
        console.log (date);
        do_stuff(date);
    }
);
```

From the [docs (find with Ctrl+f)](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#reference):

> Callback that will trigger when the user clicks a selectable date.

<kbd>**[Example](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#examples)**</kbd> (*check example #3*)

Comment: Okay that worked in terms of getting the correct value and displaying it to the console. However the date no longer shows up in the select box. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It appears that changing onClick overrides and replaces the normal behavior. To also get it to display the date in the select box I had to add `target.val(
        date.getMonth() + '/' +
        date.getDate() + '/'
        date.getFullYear();)` inside the onclick function.

Comment: @MarlonDyck well, I'm surprised with that behaviour. Never see anything like that.

Comment: It actually shows that in the documentation examples as well, so this must be something to do with a newer version.